How to read a SharePoint excel file using java program
The current task I am working on requires the need to pull data for a excel sheet that was shared to me through share point and manipulate that data using a .java file. I do have experience pulling data from excel using Eclipse Apache POI when the excel file is saved within a folder.
I've seen Microsoft Graph API or SharePoint REST API as options on the web, but I was unable to correctly pull data using those methods.
I am hoping for a basic example or suggestion of how I would be able to pull the data.

I think you need to improve the quality of your question. If you have not already done so, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].
